# Pi not connecting to Router

Tags: networking, pi-2, dhcp

I have my Pi connected to my TP-Link router using a LAN cable. I assigned a static IP on the DHCP of the router for the MAC ID of the pi. This works fine if I switch on the Pi after switching on the router.

Now, I have a single power switch that switches on the router as well as the Pi and I see that at times, the Pi do not get connected, means if I try to connect to the Pi from the network (LAN) I cannot connect to it. If I disconnect the power to the Pi and reconnect, it gets connected.

I see that in such a condition the LED on the Pi that shows network activity goes down. I tried setting up the static IP on the Pi as well (the same IP that the DHCP is configured to lease). Doing this, I see that the Network LED still shows up, but the Pi is not reachable.

Is there a way that I can configure the Pi to delay the network activation or retry it later?

My current /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
```

What I tried:

I put static IP in /etc/network/interfaces like this

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.8.19.99
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.8.19.0
broadcast 10.8.19.255
gateway 10.8.19.71
```

I also tried the way as mentioned here: https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-give-your-raspberry-pi-a-static-ip-address-update

As I said, if I switch on the router and the Pi together, the Pi does not get connected. However, if I switch off the Pi and switch it back on while the router is still running, the Pi gets connected.

Comment: Why do you need a static IP, most cases it is not needed. Second assuming you are running a recent version of Raspbian there is a setting in raspi-config that allows you to wait for the network to come up.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRobillard. I need the IP to be fixed as I run few applications like OwnCloud etc and also access it from the internet. So I need to be able to put a NAT entry on the router.

Comment: why not just give the Pi a static IP outside of the DHCP scope instead of a reserved DHCP one?

Comment: @stevieb, if you go through the post, I have tried that too. In that case, the Pi can connect to the world, but the reverse doesn't happen, as I fail to ping or connect to it. However, changing the raspi-config, it seems it is now working.

Comment: This is still not working!

Comment: It seems, nobody could follow this or resolve this